# Separate camera class or merged all together?

Tags: java, android, class, android-layout, android-camera

I have an app that requires user to take a picture and then upload via HTTP post

so, i've written my camera codes&layout(call backs, surface view, buttons etc...) together with my imageupload class

when the user press the take picture button:
all current layout are set to GONE

and show camera UI

```
imageupload_UI.setVisibility(View.GONE); //incl. upload button etc..
camera_UI.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //incl. surface view, buttons etc.
```

this is done all within one class and one layout xml file

so, my question:

Is It better(more common) to separate the camera codes into a different class & custom layout and call it via Intent
or use my current setup(all together)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate. High cohesion, low coupling. That is the way.

Comment: can you briefly explain why? i mean different class... vs same class... please tell me more

Comment: In general, it's easier to maintain, read, test, debug, reuse, understand and design a small class that does one thing and one thing well than a giant class that has too many (possibly unrelated) responsibilities.